# Spring 3 MVC Nesting RequestMapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

From Spring Official Document, Spring 3 MVC look to be support nesting Request Mapping.
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/pdf/spring-framework-reference.pdf
In page 448, they mentioned:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/appointments")
public class AppointmentsController {
//...
    @RequestMapping(value="/new", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public AppointmentForm getNewForm() {
        return new AppointmentForm();
    }
//...
}
```

(I have eliminated some code for readability)
In such case, they claimed that a request to `/appoinments/new` will invoke the `getNewForm` method.
However, it doesn't work with my local Google App Engine server (though GAE server works just fine with mapping that are not nested).
I create an example controller like below:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/basic.do")
public class HelloWorldController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/hello", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView helloWorld() {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        mav.setViewName("basic/helloWorld");
        mav.addObject("message", "Hello World From Phuong!");
        return mav;
    }
}
```

but a request to `/basic.do/hello` always results in 404 error.

Wonder if anything wrong there?
I'm using annotation-driven mode with `*.do` request handled by spring `DispatchServlet`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

try this

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/basic")
public class HelloWorldController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/hello.do", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView helloWorld() {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        mav.setViewName("basic/helloWorld");
        mav.addObject("message", "Hello World From Phuong!");
        return mav;
    }
}
```

and try with the `basic/hello.do` url

The reason is that `/basic.do/hello` is not going to be handled by your dispatcher servlet as it is not an URL that ends in .do

BTW, .html extensions are nicer than .do, IMHO

Comment: And no extension is nicer than .html

Comment: Actually "no extension" is nicer than .html ;)